# Cypher returning duplicate results when relationship is referenced

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-driver

I have a cypher query that returns list of users that are recommended to a user to follow, but am getting duplicate results when the cypher is executed.

Here is the cypher query:

```
MATCH (user:User { id: $userId })
MATCH (user)-[interestRel:INTERESTED_IN]->()<-[:INTERESTED_IN]-(recommendedUsers)
WITH DISTINCT recommendedUsers, interestRel, user
WHERE NOT recommendedUsers = user AND
    NOT exists((user)-[:FOLLOWING]->(recommendedUsers))
RETURN recommendedUsers {
    .id,
    following: false
} ORDER BY interestRel.interestLevel DESC SKIP $skip LIMIT $limit
```

I understand there will be duplicates because a user might be `INTERESTED_IN` multiple nodes, so when the `INTERESTED_IN` relationship is traversed, for each node that has a `INTERESTED_IN` relationship, duplicate users will be returned. But am returning `DISTINCT` users, so I don't understand why duplicate users are still returned.

I noticed that when the `INTERESTED_IN` relationship is bound to a variable (`interestRel`) which is used in the query, that's when duplicate results are returned.

How do I get rid of the duplicates and still reference the `INTERESTED_IN` (`interestRel`) relationship?

Comment: You can sum the interest level, which would make sense i guess

Comment: Yes, I think so. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

DISTINCT in your case filters out distinct *combinations* of recommendedUsers,interestRel, user   , not just distinct users. So when you have a recommendedUser that has two common interests with user, it is logical that he shows up twice.

It seems that you are interested to return the `recommendedUser`s that are interested in something in which `user` is highly interested in.

That said, I would write the query as follows:

```
MATCH (user:User { id: $userId })-[interestRel:INTERESTED_IN]->()<-[:INTERESTED_IN]-(recommendedUser)
WITH user,recommendedUser,
     MAX(interestRel.interestLevel) AS interestLevel
WHERE NOT recommendedUser = user AND
      NOT exists((user)-[:FOLLOWING]->(recommendedUser))
RETURN interestLevel,
       recommendedUser {
                 .id,
                 following: false
       } ORDER BY interestLevel DESC SKIP $skip LIMIT $limit
```

NOTE: I use the singular version, so *recommendedUser* b/c I think it makes the query easier to understandab.

Comment: Thank you, but using `MAX(interestRel.interestLevel)` will return the highest interest of the user and `ORDER` with that, which makes the  `ORDER`ing thesame for all recommendedUser. I think what I need is `sum(interestRel.interestLevel)` which will `sum` the `interestLevel` for all the path where a `recommendedUser` is found. This makes the `interestLevel` different for each `recommendedUser`.

Comment: You can use SUM() too indeed, depending on what you need.you could end up with 20 matched of level 1 ,compared to 4 matches of level 5 …